# Deploy war in multiple module project on maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, bamboo

I have a project structure which is like

```
Parent
|-- child Project1 (Making war project.war)
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- child Project
|   `-- pom.xml
`-- child ProjectN
    `-- pom.xml
```

The child project have references to the parent. I have configured my plan on bamboo in three stages

-- get Auth

-- default( executing unit tests)

-- deploy war( deploy and publish war )

My war file is being made in Child Project1 which holds the reference to parent. 
 In the third stage, want to configure my bamboo plan to automate the war making process. The problem I am facing is when i am checking our from the "parent" level, it dosen't gets the upload goal. If I checkout from the child and try to make a war, then it gives the error that it is not able to find the parent

***NOTE***: The parent pom.xml has references to child modules

Comment: "...holds the reference to parent." What do you mean?

Comment: The child pom.xml references to parent like 
<parent>
       .
       .
 </parent>

Comment: Child pom.xml typically references its parent. That's how it inherits. Are you trying to explicitly define the build order of your child modules?

Comment: No, I have not defined the build order, I one of the child project in which making and deploying the war is defined for whole project. I am facing issues in making the war

Comment: The deploy war cannot be from parent pom as the packaging type of parent type of parent pom is "pom"
<packaging>pom</packaging>

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As i understand from your post, you can't create a war or what?

Comment: yes I am not able to create the war file

Comment: What is "it dosen't gets the upload goal?" You need to be more specific about what maven build plugins you have configured, the command line you are using, error message you are seeing, etc.

Comment: The goal 
<execution>
                        <id>upload-war</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>upload</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
it is configured in a child project, whose packaging is of war 
<packaging>war</packaging>.
But if I checkout from child project it dosen't get the parent pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a full build at the 'Parent' level using

`mvn install`

Then have a second task that runs

`mvn upload -pl childfolder`

Or you might even be able to run

`mvn upload -am -pl childfolder`

This should build a reactor for the childfolder, building all dependancies first.

Look into the -am and -pl flags to maven, they can probably do what you want.

Comment: I am running the tests on Bamboo server

Comment: Bamboo is just an automation of anything you can run locally, just determine what you can do locally and replicate these commands and settings in bamboo.

Comment: Thanks Steve, it worked for me, after running a task "mvn install" at parent level on bamboo, I was able to make the war file.